# unzip larger zip packages equal to or greater than 3-4GB (Flash and objective c)

Tags: ios, c, flash, unzip

In my application i need to download and unzip few zip packages which are larger than 3-4 GB in memory size.

For flash version (used in Win7 and MAC OS) i used unzip.exe 5.x earlier which had support of upto 2GB.
I tried unzip.exe ver 6.0 the option for providing unzip location is not good.

Also i am looking for some good library for the same purpose in objective-c or c (iOS supported).

base requirement is to unzip the downloaded zip file from some temp location needs to be unzipped at some pre-defined path (downloaded file path and unzipped file path are different).

Comment: The problem may be with even downloading the files of that size due to documents limit: https://discussions.apple.com/message/7599983?messageID=7599983#7599983?messageID=7599983

Comment: I checked files before unzipping them via my app, they were just as expected. Unzipping them in my app using Flash environment is what gives some pain.

Also Flash api returns unsigned integer as datatype, so i am again stuck with showing download progress in exact bytes.

Comment: Anonymous downvote after a year of posting this question! Could downvoter please provide what should be updated/edited?

Answer (score 1):

I have used [ZipArchive](https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive) without any issues.

Comment: ZipArchive is useful for iOS and MAC, but My app for Desktop is for MAC and Windows both....